# How to get the input value from multiple value when button pressed php

Tags: php

i want to make a cart and my product is pizza. 
so i'm listing all the menu to the table, and add a button to submit menu to cart.

here's my index.php

```
<?php
require("connect.php");
$result = mysqli_query($con,'select * from menu');
?>


<form action="cart.php" method="get">
    <table  border="1" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Pizza Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Buy</th>
        </tr>
        <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $product->nama_menu; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product->harga_menu; ?></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="20"></td>
                <td><button type="submit" name="id" value="<?php echo $product->id_menu; ?>">Add To Cart</button></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

But when i pressed the button "Add To Cart", it sends all the quantity from the menu listing and can't be read in my cart.php

can anyone help me how to get the right quantity value when i pressed the button add to cart.

Comment: can you please show your output and your desire output.

Comment: You are keeping the same name for all inputs in the loop. Make it as array name="quantity[]"

Comment: The easiest way might be to use a simple javascript function attached to each button ( change it's type to `button` rather than `submit` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make separate form for each of the item. Try below code.

```
<?php
require("connect.php");
$result = mysqli_query($con,'select * from menu');
?>



    <table  border="1" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Pizza Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Buy</th>
        </tr>
        <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){ ?>
            <form action="cart.php" method="get">
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $product->nama_menu; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product->harga_menu; ?></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="20"></td>
                <td><button type="submit" name="id" value="<?php echo $product->id_menu; ?>">Add To Cart</button></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use array in name then submit it will give you seperate quantity.

```
<td><input type="number" name="quantity[<?php echo $product->nama_menu; ?>]" min="1" max="20">
```

**Output:**
quantity['pizza1'] = 10
quantity['pizza2'] = 20
....

Another Option is use dynamic name for number.

```
<td><input type="number" name="quantity_<?php echo $product->nama_menu; ?>" min="1" max="20">
```

**Output:**
quantity_pizza1 = 10
quantity_pizza2 = 20
....

Comment: Is this useful to you or not. Please feedback us. @Shasapo

Comment: i try this too, it works, but i want to keep it simple and not using array. thankyou for your answer :D

Comment: Yes so I have added another option which is best for you. @Shasapo